# How to get non-programmers to understand domain model

Tags: testing, domain-driven-design

When working on a complicated project, many people will involved in the developemnt, over a long time span. Therefore comes the problem of how to get everyone involved to understand the domain model.

When a project is first developed following DDD, it's probably well discussed among all people, and is designed carefully. At this stage it's relatively easy for everyone to understand and agree on the underlying domain model.

However as the project iterated over a longer period, different groups of people may be involved and few people could still hold the full picture. Even if the code is very well maintained, it's hard for non-programmers, including domain expert/ product managers/ testers, to grasp the business rules embeded in the code.

The only way out I could think of, is to keep the documents/umls/graphs well maintained for each changes, and always reflect the underlying model. However I think this is a huge challenge for any non-trival project. And it's very hard to decide how much details need to be included in the document.

Is there any best practice which I could learn from, such that the domain model could be well understood by people, and is also easy to evolve with the product?

Comment: It turns out there's a whole book about this - https://leanpub.com/livingdocumentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use Behaviour Driven Development (BDD)**.

BDD is like TDD. But BDD always focuses on testing domain *behaviour*, and tests are defined using the domain's *Ubiquitous Language*.  All stories/features/scenarios can be written in a structured, human readable form ([like this](https://www.modernanalyst.com/Resources/Articles/tabid/115/ID/3871/BDD-An-introduction-to-feature-files.aspx))

And because the tests are tightly coupled to your code, **they have to stay in sync** (assuming that your team is disciplined in keeping tests up-to-date).

In my experience, this offers the most economical solution for exposing up-to-date domain rules in a moderately readable format.

Comment: Guys, don't miss this answer. We've worked in many projects and BDD is incredible to have business rules understandable by not technical users at the same those rules are tested. Users are able even to write the tests, forcing them to declare all the cases that their business model needs (no more undefined cases!).

Comment: sounds great, will have a try

Answer (score 0):

The most important strategy that comes from the DDD are the [Bounded contexts](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html). This corresponds to the (sub)domains in the business. Ideally they should map one to one. So, the first step that should be done is to clearly identify the (sub)domains; this is also the hardest.

Instead of keeping a lot of diagrams with a lot of details that are hard to keep up to date with the project, one should draw a context map.

[image: https://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-contextmapping]

After this you have already split the problem in pieces that are more manageable. Seeing a context map one could understand the big picture in a manner of minutes.

For each (sub)domain you can keep a list of main business rules. The Task management software (i.e. Jira) could be the single source of truth for these.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Could you elaborate more on using Jira as source of truth? I mean it just contains a bunch of changes, somewhat like event source. It's it pretty inconvenient to get the current "snapshot" ?

Comment: @fankai the current "snapshot" is the code but the code that doesn't follow the DDD is hard to reverse engineer into business rules.

Comment: sorry by snapshot I mean the current effective business rules. I mean how a non-programmer, could grasp the current effective business rules from Jira ?

Comment: take the cargo example in Evans' book, there was a **10%** overbooking rule. Say 6 months later, this is changed to **20%**. There did have a Jira story for this change, and the code changed accordingly. However, say after another year, how could people find out that current rule is **20%** without checking code ?  Maybe we could try searching in Jira, but that doesn't sound very accurate.

Comment: @fankai indeed, searching Jira is not very accurate. A non-programmer cannot understand code so a separate business rules document seems to be necessary. In my current working place the boss is asking me, the programmer, what are the business rules because he forgets and I tell him: let me just see the code. If I used DDD the answer comes very quickly.

Comment: Haha, that's pretty like what's going on in my company. Right, the bottom line is that with DDD, at least it should be easy for programmers to understand the model. Yet there is risk that the boss is not aware that the code is not what he expected. It's no way for managers to make good planning if they don't know how exactly the system is working now.